# Laravel 5.7 Collection get size and offset after pagination

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pagination, laravel-5.7

I have a paginated collection like

```
Post::where('active', 1)->paginate(10)
```

and I would like to get the start and end position of the current portion of collection.
I mean if page is 2 and page limit is 10 then the start position is 11 and end position is 20. I need to render a text like products from 11 to 20 of total 284 products. Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following methods will return the information you want:

```
$pagination = Post::where('active', 1)->paginate(10);

$pagination->firstItem(); // Returns the number of the first item from the current page

$pagination->lastItem(); // Returns the number of the last item from the current page

$pagination->total(); // Returns the total amount of items
```

You can find all available methods [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Contracts/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html).

If you convert the pagination into an array or JSON it will automatically add all the meta information.

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination#converting-results-to-json):

> The JSON from the paginator will include meta information such as
> `total`, `current_page`, `last_page`, and more. The actual result objects
> will be available via the data key in the JSON array. Here is an
> example of the JSON created by returning a paginator instance from a
> route:

```
{
   "total": 50,
   "per_page": 15,
   "current_page": 1,
   "last_page": 4,
   "first_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=1",
   "last_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=4",
   "next_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=2",
   "prev_page_url": null,
   "path": "http://laravel.app",
   "from": 1,
   "to": 15,
   "data":[
        {
            // Result Object
        },
        {
            // Result Object
        }
   ]
}
```